# Request.Form[cboCustomer.UniqueID] gives null value

Tags: asp.net, forms, web

IN my application we have below control in aspx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboCustomer" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" MaxLength="50"
 TabIndex="5"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In page load method or any post back method

> Request.Form[cboCustomer.UniqueID]

always returns null value.Not sure why it is happening.Because of this form's values are not getting accessed.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Request.Form`? Could you not able to access `cboCustomer` directly?

Comment: We are using Callback to populate this control , so if we do not get updated values during final save (since viewstate does not get updated)

Comment: Could you post the code?